# Parameter is not valid - System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Ms)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve the image from the database for a particular user after logging into the program. The problem I encountered is "Parameter is not valid."

The code:

```
Dim ArrImage() As Byte
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("server=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=hazimdb;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim Ms As New IO.MemoryStream 
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM userlog WHERE username= '" & Label10.Text.Trim & "'", cn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        Label10.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("username")
        If Not IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0).Item("pictu")) Then
            ArrImage = dt.Rows(0).Item("pictu")
            For Each arr As Byte In ArrImage
                Ms.WriteByte(arr)
            Next
            PictureBox8.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Ms)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("No Match Found")
    End If
```

Comment: If you upload an image, can you verify that the data in the database is the same as the data in the file? Also, what if my user is called: ' or username like '%

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Answer (score 1):

Set the memory stream position to 0 before trying to get an image out of it.

```
Ms.Flush()
Ms.Position = 0
```